# How to deploy this rare Spring MVC web app?

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, deployment

I'm newbie in Spring MVC. I can't run this app: http://www.softwarereality.com/usecasedriven/InternetBookstore.zip
I tried with Netbeans buiding a web app from existing sources, Eclipse importing the proyect(Spring Tool Suite) and Tomcat standalone copying the folder but I had no success.
Some help please. Thanks.

Note: This libs are necessary: http://www.softwarereality.com/usecasedriven/lib.zip

Answer (score 0):

The following project can be imported into Eclipse by following the below steps:

- Create a new dynamic project in Eclipse.
- Go to File->Import->General->Archive File
- Select the zip file you downloaded and set the parent folder to the newly created Web project name.
- Import all the lib files into the classpath (Check the included readme.txt to find the JARS needed to run the project.

Hope it helps. :)